# pymongo count_doucment() not working with datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mongodb

Hi i am trying to query data from mongodb using python = 3.8, django=4.2.2, arrow==1.2.3 pymongo = 3.13.0, mongodb is serverless.

this is my filter object

```
filter['created_at']={
        '$gte': arrow.now(settings.LOCAL_TIME_ZONE).shift(hours=-24).span('day')[0].to(settings.TIME_ZONE).datetime,
        '$lt': arrow.now(settings.LOCAL_TIME_ZONE).span('day')[1].to(settings.TIME_ZONE).datetime,
        }
```

when i print filter['created_at'] i get output as

```
'created_at': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 22, 18, 30, tzinfo=tzutc()), '$lt': datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 24, 18, 29, 59, 999999, tzinfo=tzutc())}
```

and this is my count function

```
def count(self, filters={}):
    q = self.collection.count_documents(filters)
    return q
```

I am not getting data when i pass filter['created_at'], and when i pass empty {} in filter i get count of documents and also mongodb is serverless.

Can anyone help me out! What is the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

If your object is indeed

```py
filter['created_at']={
        '$gte': arrow.now(settings.LOCAL_TIME_ZONE).shift(hours=-24).span('day')[0].to(settings.TIME_ZONE).datetime,
        '$lt': arrow.now(settings.LOCAL_TIME_ZONE).span('day')[1].to(settings.TIME_ZONE).datetime,
        }
```

then `print filter['created_at']` cannot produce the output you describe; the `created_at` key would be lost.  Change your call to your `count()` function to pass `filter`, not `filter['created_at']`.